Status in MS Navision related to Jobs
One of the reports generated related to JobList from Microsoft Navison includes the column called Status and following statuses are available there.
Open, Completed, Pending Approval, Quote, Quote Approved, Unsuccessful
Could you please help me on identifying from which underline table these statuses are generated. Seems these are not the Job status.

No version of Nav mentioned, no report number provided. One needs to read minds to help you.
